# Apply permissions on WPF UI controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, permissions, roles

I working in WPF application with multiple screens. And now we are creating the security of Roles. The schema the we have is like the following:
Every ***User*** can have multiple roles, and every ***Role*** has multiple permissions. ***Permission*** is a pair as: (Object, AccessLevel).
And ***Access Levels*** are (Read, Modify, Non-Visible).

the client side gets the permissions as a dictionary< string, string> contains permissions of all user's roles:

- The first string is the object that we have to apply the access-level
  on it.
- The second string is the access level.

And I have a SecurityManager which is singleton, contains a dictionary < string, string> and related methods. One method returns the permission for specific object.

```
public String GetModuleUserSettings(string SecurableObj)
        {
            if (!this.ContainObjectPermission(SecurableObj))
                this.mPermissions[SecurableObj] = new String();

            return this.mPermissions[SecurableObj].Clone();
        }
```

What I need is, to use this singleton in xaml,

```
<Control IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static SecurityManager.Instance.Permissions[ControlName]}, Converter={}}"
```

I have some problems:

1- If I could have to apply on my own control and UIelements that Im using a method called SetSecurity(), takes the ObjectName and returns the access-level.

2- These two properties (IsEnabled, Visibility) are the target properties to apply the access-level on any control(object).But both have been binded to another properties for other reason! For example:

```
IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Comment: So what is your question ? I just see statements here

Comment: I mentioned the problems:1- If I could have to apply on my own control and UIelements that Im using a method called SetSecurity(), takes the ObjectName and returns the access-level.

2- These two properties (IsEnabled, Visibility) are the target properties to apply the access-level on any control(object).But both have been binded to another properties for other reason!

Comment: So i am absolutely unable to understand your question... What do you expect from us ? Code, hints, suggestions ? Because "1- If I could have to apply on my own control and UIelements that Im using a method called SetSecurity(), takes the ObjectName and returns the access-level." looks like a code request, wich aren't granted here

Comment: @yanyankelevich Can I force all UIElements in my applications to override a method I will create it called (SetSecurity)?